# Output Compression in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Is it `common practice` nowadays to enable output compression on [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) ?

Comment: Output compression is a good practice to speed up the site and also it saves the bandwidth and it's only not related to `CodeIgniter` but the `web` programming. I use most of the times output compression, (CI, WordPress) but can't tell you wheather it's a common or not and maybe no one can be so sure about this.

Comment: So it is well 'supported' by browsers I guess (the most common at least) ?